# RestKit not mapping objects because of another object mapping

Tags: ios, restkit

I have two objects, item and category. I have concrete urls for most queries so the mapping is fine. But for certain item request I have dynamic mapping that changes URLS and it looks like this:

```
[RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:goodMapping
                                        pathPattern:nil
                                            keyPath:nil
                                        statusCodes:statusCodes]
```

If this is present, my Categories fail to map, although this is item mapping. If I comment this line out everything works fine.
My problem is that I can't set pathPattern, because even if I set the path to actual path it fails to detect it, here is the error I get:

```
failed to match: response path 'catalog/item?category_id=2' did not match the path pattern 'catalog/item?category_id=2'
```

I tried replacing "2" with ":id" to no avail. I can't set keyPath either, because I am getting unnamed array from server.

How do I change my mapping so it mapped my objects and detected them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make it work by exactly matching pathPattern to request url, ignoring all get parameters, so it was "catalog/item" in request and "catalog/item" in mapping and everything worked, even if the resulting url is catalog/item?category_id=2.